# How to execute or read xlsx file data by bash script

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I have a bash script that's working like deploy resources in Azure Portal from CSV file .
But the problem is that ,

Is it possible to do the same job from xlsx file .

I do not know , how to execute that .

Someone come 6 help me here please .

I left my script & xlsx below here :

```html
#!/bin/bash
az login --tenant ca64240a-78a0-4116-9504-eab6ead602b9 # DEV
az login --tenant ca64240a-78a0-4116-9504-eab6ead602b9 # TEST
# az login --tenant ca64240a-78a0-4116-9504-eab6ead602b9 # STAGE
# az login --tenant ca64240a-78a0-4116-9504-eab6ead602b9 # PROD


# Prompt for the CSV file path
read -p "Enter the path to the CSV file for SP to Group Member : " csv_file

# Check if the CSV file exists
if [ -f "$csv_file" ]; then
    # Read CSV file and populate arrays
    while IFS=',' read -r GroupID ServicePrincipal Subscription; do
        csv_row+=("$GroupID;$ServicePrincipal;$Subscription")
    done < "$csv_file"

    # Process Service Principals
    echo " Creating Service Principles to groups .... "

    for row in "${csv_row[@]}"; do
        IFS=';' read -ra ARRAY <<< "$row"
        groupId=${ARRAY[0]}
        sp_name=${ARRAY[1]}
        subscription=${ARRAY[2]}
        spObjId=$(az ad sp list --display-name "$sp_name" --query '[0].id' --output tsv)
        echo $spObjId
        if [ -n "$spObjId" ]; then
            # set the subscription
            az account set --subscription $subscription
            # execute the command against the subscription
            az ad group member add --group "$groupId" --member-id "$spObjId"
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) added to AAD Group '$groupId' successfully."
            else
                echo "Failed to add Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) to AAD Group '$groupId'."
            fi
        else
            echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name not found."
        fi
    done
else
    echo "CSV file not found at the specified path."
fi
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to do the same job from xlsx file(?)"* . Yes, it is very likely. But, sorry, StackOverflow isn't a code translation service. And only a few `bash` readers will be capable to helping with this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel for list of possible programming languages you can add as a tag so you will get skilled readers thinking about your problem. Voting-to-close. Sorry, but Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the easiest way would be to install xlsx2csv either with your relevent package manager, or by going to https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv

Then you can simple convert the xlsx document to csv, and then your script will work the same way.

Alternatively, xlsx documents are just a zip file of xml documents, you could unzip the xlsx, and then either modify your script to populate from the xml directly, or you could convert the xml into csv, and run your script unedited.

That should get your started.